# How to convert from raw disk image to OVF

Tags: conversion, virtual-disk

How do I convert a virtual appliance image in `RAW` format (in)directly to `OVF`/`OVA` format?

There is a tool called [ovftools](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/getting-started/learn/ovf.html) that allows the conversion from `.ovf/.ova/.vmx` to `.ovf/.ova/.vmx`. but it doesn't appear to support `RAW` disk as an input format.

Virtual Box also has VBoxManage allowing you to convert from `VDI|VMDK|VHD|RAW` to `VDI|VMDK|VHD|RAW` but nothing about`OVF/OVA` format.

I'm running Ubuntu/Debian GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that I want to say before I go on in case of confusion is that `RAW`,`VMDK`,`VHD`,`VDI`  are all (virtual`*`) hard drive files, where as `OVF`,`OVA`,`.VMX` are Virtual Machine settings files. An `OVF` File comes with a separate virtual hard drive (which can be in VMDK format, or one of a few others), where as a `OVA` file is a contained all in one virtual machine.

(`*` - Majority are virtual!)

I have personally not seen a Virtual Machine boot from a RAW drive before. If you can convert a `RAW` to a `VMDK` using `VBoxManage` I would the recommend using `VMWare Player or Workstation` (for sure) or Virtual Box (not so sure!) to create a new Virtual Machine and select the `VMDK` file you just converted.

Again, I am not sure what Virtual Box uses as it's default settings file, but, I know VMWare Workstation uses `VMX`, you should then have no problems using `ovftools` as you will have a new Virtual Machine with the correct hard drive.

After looking around, the only tool I could find is [Live View](http://liveview.sourceforge.net/) which can convert a Raw file to a VMDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as you say .OVF and .VMX are configuration files and not disk images. OVA is overall packaging format. Conversion between images and configuration files are different things. After a more deep search I also found this project [open-ovf](http://gitorious.org/open-ovf/mainline/commits/master) that help me to create OVF/OVA. The [virt-convert](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Community+Group+xen/OVFsupport) is very useful too. Regards!

Comment: I am not sure how clear I was - to sum up completely... What I was really trying to get across is that if you basically convert the raw to a VMDK, then set up a new virtual machine that points to that hard drive, it will generate a .vmx file. You can then convert that VMX to OVF, along with the VMDK virtual hard drive... so, you will do what you originally asked and be converting a RAW to OVF

Comment: I understand your idea: RAW -> .VMDK along .VMX then VMX -> .OVF using the same .VMDK disk. At the beginning I was thinking that OVF is a disk image format, but I was wrong about it. Now I see that OVF is an standard to define/specify virtual machines and not a binary disk image format.

Answer (score 3):

`.ova` files are just a Posix tar file:

```
$ file foo.ova
foo.ova:            POSIX tar archive
```

If you decompress it, you'll find one `.ovf` (XML) file describing the VM, one text file with checksums (SHA-1), and one or more `.vmdk` files:

```
$ file *                                                                                                                                                                        
foo-disk1.vmdk:                        VMware4 disk image                                                                                                                                                          
foo-disk2.vmdk:                        VMware4 disk image                                                                                                                                                          
foo-disk3.vmdk:                        VMware4 disk image                                                                                                                                                          
foo-disk4.vmdk:                        VMware4 disk image                                                                                                                                                          
foo-disk5.vmdk:                        VMware4 disk image                                                                                                                                                          
foo.ova:                               POSIX tar archive                                                                                                                                                           
foo.mf:                                ASCII text                                                                                                                                                                  
foo.ovf:                               XML 1.0 document, ASCII text, with very long lines
```

So for a RAW `.ova` conversion, you will have to convert your raw files to `.vmdk` format, write the right `.ovf` file, create the `.mf` file, and tar everything into an `.ova` file. Notice that the latter does not include compression. The lines in the `.mf` file look like this:

```
SHA1(foo.ovf)= e33370daa74544dc30841e1c527628e5c8610c54
```

It can be easily obtained from `sha1sum`, but the format is different:

```
$ sha1sum 'foo.ovf'
e33370daa74544dc30841e1c527628e5c8610c54  foo.ovf
```

So:

```
$ sha1sum *.ovf *.vmdk | awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS = "40 2 1024" } { print "SHA1(" $3 ")= " $1 }'
SHA1(HyperFile 3.3.0.ovf)= e33370daa74544dc30841e1c527628e5c8610c54
SHA1(HyperFile_3.3.0-disk1.vmdk)= a60c58d00010bdc715d96e89e34fd45f48a58b4c
SHA1(HyperFile_3.3.0-disk2.vmdk)= 92250a09ef4b924c51c64b37ba6dc7049eb24cc2
SHA1(HyperFile_3.3.0-disk3.vmdk)= aff779bf46c859506606fd8925f79ffb9a86d955
SHA1(HyperFile_3.3.0-disk4.vmdk)= 64dd05f7e5d73929234393c109b2d92d69dedc8e
SHA1(HyperFile_3.3.0-disk5.vmdk)= 157e9f9f6adeabcc41f228cd7b53fc0ef4da43f9
```

I'll let you read about the OVF format here: https://www.dmtf.org/standards/ovf

Answer (score 0):

I use Vboxmanage to convert raw to vdi. I then create a new machine in Vbox using the vdi file as the virtual disk. I start the new machine once to make sure it works. After shutdown I export the machine as an Ova file. Most VM tools such as Vbox will allow the ova to be imported and will run the machine.

Vboxmanage convertfromraw     - - format /vdi